# Can parameters to dust.js helpers be anything but a string (e.g. an array)?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

While parsing JSON data with a dust.js template, I call a helper and pass an array from the JSON data to the helper as one of its parameters. It's an array of strings like:

```
"foo": ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Inside the dust.js helper the value becomes this string: "a, b, c". typeof reports its type as a string. Is there a way to thwart this automatic conversion? I don't want to do a split on the commas, because the individual strings in the array may contain commas.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you pass in param into a helper. `{@myHelpers arrayParam=myArray /}` will be passed in as Array (granted that myArray is an Array) vs `{@myHelper arrayParam="{myArray}"/}` will be passed in as a String because of the interpolation. Note how first example does not have `{}` around `myArray` param.

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6rP/) of these two examples in JSFiddle.